# Nginx downloads php files, instead of executing

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx

I've tried every possible combination with no success.
My setup is basically as described here:
https://devanswers.co/install-php-nginx-ubuntu-20-04/

I am on Google Cloud Compute Engine, VM instance with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, PHP 8.0 and Nginx plus Cloudflare proxy. SSL enabled with CF cert.

FPM8.0 is Active and working fine.
All php files are being offered as downloads instead of rendering them.
HTML pages work fine.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Hi Adam. Thank you. Here you go:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, 
ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##
        gzip on;
        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json 
application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss 
text/javascript;
        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##
        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
#mail {
#       # See sample authentication script at:
#       # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
#
#       # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#       # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#       # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
#
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:110;
#               protocol   pop3;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
#
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:143;
#               protocol   imap;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
#}
```

Then php-fpm config:

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; FPM Configuration ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; All relative paths in this configuration file are relative to PHP's 
install
; prefix (/usr). This prefix can be dynamically changed by using the
; '-p' argument from the command line.
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Global Options ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
[global]

pid = /run/php/php8.0-fpm.pid
include=/etc/php/8.0/fpm/pool.d/*.conf
```

Nginx config file:

```
    server {

        root /var/www/sw;
        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        server_name mydomainname.com www.mydomainname.com;
        location / {
           # try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;

        }

     listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
     listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot

     ssl_certificate         /etc/ssl/cert.pem;
     ssl_certificate_key     /etc/ssl/key.pem;
     ssl_client_certificate /etc/ssl/cloudflare.crt;
     ssl_verify_client on;

}

server {
   # ... some other code
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock;
    }

}
server {
    if ($host = www.mydomainname.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } 
    if ($host = mydomainname.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } 
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name mydomainname.com www.mydomainname.com;
    return 404;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name mydomainname.com www.mydomainname.com;
    return 302 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: Can you post your nginx config files including `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` and  any virtual host configs as well as your php-fpm config. Also who owns the php files and what permissions are on them?

Answer (score 0):

I think your php location is following:
`/var/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock;` instead of `/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock;`

```
server {
   # ... some other code
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock;
        # php location is above
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. delete file-link "default" that placed in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled . Only site.conf should stay in this directory.
2. systemctl restart php8.1-fpm
3. systemctl restart nginx
4. systemctl status php8.1-fpm.service - should be ok
5. clean browser cash or rename test file (info.php ->info2.php)
6. Enjoy!